# Android: Place picker search nearby first

Tags: android, android-location

I am using Google's [Place Picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) to get the location (either the current location or the location of the place he searches for). Everything works very fine, but have the following problem.

Suppose I am in Bangalore, India, when I search for a hotel, say "Leela Palace" when I type "Lee" the AutoComplete displays "Leeds, United Kingdom", "Leensburg, VA United States" etc...

How can we make the autocomplete first search the nearby places first rather than other countries.

Comment: use location service to get your current location

Comment: getting current location is not the issue here. The autocomplete search bar in PlacePicker is not search nearby places first.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a filter first:

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder(). setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY).setCountry("IN").build();//results are filtered within India
```

Now pass this filter to the Intent:

```
PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN) .setFilter(typeFilter) .build(this);
```

Comment: I want the map as well, I get map and search both in PlacePicker (link given in the question). but we can set the above way in that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pafSetLocation);

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
            .build();
    placeAutocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

You can also visit https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search for more help.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't show nearest result first. The `TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS` basically `Only return geocoding results with a precise address.` as per Google Docs here : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html#TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS